# Android RecyclerView only display one item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried other answers but nothing worked.   for some reason RecyclerView only displaying one item. I tried changing layout height to wrap content but it didn't worked, still displaying only one item. I'm passing about 20 items.

I have to type more otherwise stackoverflow won't let me post this question. because it mostly code

feed_list_item.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTransaction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtGeneral"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

```java
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btnget;
RecyclerView recycler;
private Session session;
private TextView textViewResult;
ArrayList<Feed> feed ;
private feedadapter feedadap;
String token ="Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJ ";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https:url/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<Feed> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getposts( token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Feed>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Feed> call, Response<Feed> response) {
                feed = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(response.body()));

                feedadap = new feedadapter(MainActivity.this,feed);
                recycler.setAdapter(feedadap);
              Log.d("msgcontent",feed.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Feed> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}
```

Comment: post adapter code

Comment: Post your `Feed` class

Answer (score 3):

check `getItemCount()` in your `FeedAdapter`.
it's must look like this:

```
 @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return feed.size();
  }
```

Comment: it returns 1. I cannot figure the reason

Comment: change return 1; to return feed.size();

Comment: if feed size is 1, surly size of response.body() is 1. check your backend.